# Maven build failed but exit code is still 0

Tags: bash, maven, jenkins

I ran Maven build (  `mvn clean install`) in our Jenkins pipeline, we use the Surefire plugin to run our tests, one test failed, and we see that Maven prints `BUILD FAILED` and that the exit code is 0. What's the reason for this? (Exit code 0 means Success)

My code looks like that:

```
mvn clean install
RESULT=$?
if [ $RESULT -ne 0 ];then exit 1; fi;
```

Comment: How are you calling Maven in Jenkins? Via script? Or Pipeline?

Comment: Scripted pipeline

Comment: Can you show how it looks like?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up checking the log using this condition. At first, redirecting mvn output to a file

```
mvn clean install | tee mvn_res
```

And then checking the build status using grep

```
if grep -v 'BUILD SUCCESS' mvn_res;then exit 1; fi;
```